# Design break in arabic version bouble quote not visible fully

Tags: html, css

I want to display quote in hero section along with image, design works fine for English version but it breaks in Arabic version as design is RTL.

[image]

I notice that part of double quote is partially not visible `”`. i tried everything but hides part of quote at beginning and end of quote

Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/YzjWdQJ)

```
<!-- Hero  -->
<section class="headding-news" style="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-parent-container bg-white text-center">
      <div class="flex-item-left">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x720/000/fff" class="img-responsive center" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-right speech right">
        <blockquote class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__slow">
          <p>This is the quote from some unknown person.</p>
          <cite>Person Name</cite>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<!-- Hero end -->
```

Comment: Codepen works as expected?

Comment: Possibly i fixed it